# firebase support for iOS and tvOS project using same bundle ids

Tags: firebase

I am using the same bundle ids for iOS and tvOS projects and was working fine with fabric. Now we need to migrate to Firebase and firebase is not accepting two apps with the same bundle ids. Both apps are targeting different platforms still no support for that.

Both the applications are live on AppStore.

Comment: Hello did you find any solution to this problem? We have the same issue and we are able to track error only on one platform. Any solution found?

Comment: no, I am still looking for the answers

Comment: We asked to Google support and they said that in this case we need to separate the project on firebase. Actually for us there isn’t any other solutions to this!